# Multiplication of permutations

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I'm trying to prove that given a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ where $H\leq G$ , 
and given that $aH = bH$ , then we need to check if also $Ha = Hb$ .

I'm trying to show that this is wrong with a counter example :

$G=S_{3}$  , $H={(1),(1 2)}$   , $a=(1 3)  , b=(1 2 3)$

And now we check :
$aH = (1 3)H=(1 3) ( (1),(1 2))={(1 3) ,(1 3)(1 2)} = ? $

Here , for the multiplication $(1 3)(1)$ : 1 goes to 1 and 1 goes to 3 , then the result is 1 goes to 3 .

For the second multiplication $(1 3)(1 2)$ : 1 goes to 2 , and then 1 goes to 3 ? how do I calculate this one ?

The same for bH :

$bH=(1 2 3)H=(1 2 3)  ( (1),(1 2))={(1 2 3)  ,(1 2 3)(1 2)} = ? $

How do I calculate the multiplication of $(123)(12)$ ?

Regards

Comment: Ron: *Please*: dollar signs, not quote marks.

Comment: It depends on your conventions; Herstein multiplies them left to right; most books multiply them right to left. So $(13)(12)$ would be "first $(12)$, *then* $(13)$". This would be $1\to 2\to 2$, so $1\to 2$; $2\to 1\to 3$, so $2\to 3$; and $3\to 3\to 1$, so $3\to 1$. So $(13)(12)=(123)$.

Comment: Why [tag:abelian-groups]?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thanks , but why , 3 goes to 3  (here 3→3→1) on the first hand  (and not 3 goes to 1) , and on the second hand 2 goes to 1 (here 2→1→3) and not 2 goes to 2 ?

Comment: @ron: $(12)$ sends $3$ to itself, and $(13)$ sends $3$ to $1$. So the result of applying $(13)(12)$ to $3$ is: the first permutation (namely, $(12)$) sends $3$ to $3$; then you plug in this output, $3$, into the second permutation (namely, $(13)$) which sends $3$ to $1$. So, in total, $(13)(12)$ sent $3$ to $1$. $(12)$ sends $2$ to $1$; and $(13)$ sends $1$ to $3$. So the result of applying $(13)(12)$ to $2$ is: the first permutations, $(12)$, sends $2$ to $1$; then you plug in the output $1$ into $(13)$, you get $3$. So in summary, $(13)(12)$ sends $2$ to $3$ (via $1$).

Comment: Got it ! you're indeed the king! Those permutations are pretty hard to understand sometimes! much thanks ! :)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: By the way , then (1 2 3) also means probably that I can say (2 3 1) or (3 1 2) , right ? since all the elements still are still going to the same destination !?

Comment: @ron: Yes: in cycle notation, $(a_1\cdots a_n) = (a_2\cdots a_na_1)=(a_3\cdots a_na_1a_2)=\cdots = (a_na_1\cdots a_{n-1})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the precise term you're looking for is composition of permutations.  It works exactly like composition of functions: we look at each element's image in the first permutation, then carry that image through to the next permutation, and see where it is sent there.

For the second example, $1$ would go to $2$, and then we look at $2$'s image in the next permutation, which is $3$.  This is assuming you're composing right to left, which is how your examples have been going.
Now $2$ goes to $1$ in the right permutation, and $1$ goes back to $2$ in the left permutation, so $2$'s image in the composition of both permutations is $2$.
Finally, $3$ is fixed by the first permutation, so we look at where $3$ is sent in the second permutation - it is mapped to $1$. Now, we write our result as one permutation:

$(123)(12) = (13)(2)$, or just $(13)$.

For the first, we similarly calculate $(13)(12)$.  Compactly writing the process: $1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 2, 2 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 3, 3 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 1$, so we have that $(13)(12) = (123)$.

Comment: Thanks . I need to understand something (1 2) means that 1 goes to 2 and 2 goes to 2 ? how 1 goes to 2 and 2 goes to 1 ?

Comment: $(12)$ means $1$ goes to $2$ and $2$ goes to $1$. This is **cycle notation**, not abbreviated 2-line notation. The cycle $(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)$ represents the permutation $a_1\mapsto a_2$, $a_2\mapsto a_3$, $a_3\mapsto a_3,\ldots,a_{n_1}\mapsto a_n$, and $a_n\mapsto a_1$. So $(12)$ means "$1$ goes to $2$, $2$ goes to $1$"; $(123)$ means "$1$ goes to $2$, $2$ goes to $3$, and $3$ goes to $1$". It does **not** mean $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&2&3\\1&2&3\end{array}\right)\leftarrow\text{not this}.$$